# How to constructing a binary regular expression for 8 bits, where "1 1 1" occurs twice in any configuration and the other two bits can be whatever?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, regular-expressions

I'm trying to make a regex for my language with alphabet $\Sigma = \{"0","1"\}$ that captures any 8 bits where the sequence "1 1 1" occurs twice without overlap. These two sequences can be adjacent, but don't have to be. The remaining two bits can be either "0" or "1". It doesn't matter what they are, but it needs to be possible for them to be anything.

Mainly the length limitation is what I'm struggling with. If the length was irrelevant it could have easily been
$$ \Sigma^* \circ (111) \circ \Sigma^* \circ (111) \circ \Sigma^* $$
since $\Sigma^*$ includes empty. However, the size of each realization $\Sigma^*$ depends on the realizations of the others. I have no clue how to capture this in the expression.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think there is any very concise way to do this. Just to clarify: do you mean that "111" appears at least twice or exactly twice? (I'm guessing the former since if the occurrences of "111" are adjacent then there are more than two occurrences.)

Comment: Oh yeah I mean exactly twice. Could have been clearer on that.

Comment: But if you have say "01111110", then there are four occurrences of "111".  If you really mean exactly twice, the remaining two bits have to be zero and there are only two possibilities: "11101110" and "01110111". I suggest you clarify your question

Comment: Okay, I mean without overlap

Comment: Can you please fix the question to make it clear exactly what you mean. If you have more than 6 "1"s then there are more than two non-overlapping occurrences of "111".

Answer (score 0):

As $111$ is together, we can consider this as $4$ characters of two {111} and other two as $1$ or $0$.

If other two are both $0$, we have $4 \choose 2$ ways to place two {111} them in $4$ spaces and other two places are then taken by $0$.

If other two characters are both $1$ then there is only one way to arrange as all are $1$.

If other two characters are one $1$ and one $0$, we again have $4 \choose 2$ ways to arrange. If you think of total arrangements, it is $12$ but half of them are duplicates.

So in total, we have $13$ distinct arrangements.

Comment: Another way to look at two {$111$} sequence without overlap, and one $1$ and one $0$ is arrangements of seven $1$ and one $0$, there are $\frac{8!}{7!} = 8$ distinct arrangements but $2$ of them are not allowed which are $(1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1)$ and $(1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1)$.